# Get data form csv file to dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, csv, dictionary

I've found some answers, but not with mit CSV format. I want to read the 1. and 5. position of my data.csv file and store it in a dictionary:

```
4096,1000,-,-,Berkeley Trailer nego,[Neil_Sembower]
4097,1001-100F,-,-,Berkeley Trailer encap/IP,[Neil_Sembower]
5632,1600,-,-,Valid Systems,[Neil_Sembower]
16962,4242,-,-,PCS Basic Block Protocol,[Neil_Sembower]
21000,5208,-,-,BBN Simnet,[Neil_Sembower]
24576,6000,-,-,DEC Unassigned (Exp.),[Neil_Sembower]
```

---

**Example**

I need the string from 4097:

> 4097,1001-100F,-,-,Berkeley Trailer encap/IP,[Neil_Sembower]

= **Berkeley Trailer encap/I**

---

So I need a dictionary with the 1. and 5. position (1. key / 5. value)

Have somebody an idea how I can do that?

Comment: You have two rows with no key. Cannot put that in a dictionary.

Comment: You could use https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper to parse CSV files

Comment: If you are willing to skip records with no key then you could simply parse it as a CSD into a class file of some sort. Then loop over those class records and those records with key store to dictionary

Comment: You could either use .Split() method specifying ',' as delimiter; or your could use Regex expression to retrieve the data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a possible way:

```
var pathToCSV = @"C:\...\file.csv"; //define path of csv file here
var lines = File.ReadLines(pathToCSV);  
var dictionary = lines.Select(line => line.Split(',')).ToDictionary(data => data[0], data => data[4]);
```

Can be even shorter of course:

```
var dictionary = File.ReadLines(@"C:\...\file.csv").Select(line => line.Split(',')).ToDictionary(data => data[0], data => data[4]);
```

Comment: I wouldn't rely simply on `string.Split()` for parsing CSV files. It's not that simple in many cases - for example, you have to handle escaped delimiter characters. Rather than reinventing the wheel and writing your own - probably buggy - CSV parser, I'd use a well tested one such as this one: https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper.
Also, `File.ReadLines()` should of course only be used for really small files where memory usage is not an issue.

Comment: In his example and in his question there is no sign of escape characters being used. Don't mix up ReadAllLines with ReadLines as ReadLines doesn't save all lines into memory. Otherwise you are right o course

Comment: Worked for me, thanks. One last question. Why downvote, whats wrong with my question? :)

Comment: It wasn't me but probably because of language and missing sign of research effort ^^

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"data.csv"));
var dic = new Dictionary<int, string>();

while (!reader.EndOfStream)
{
    var line = reader.ReadLine();
    var values = line.Split(',');

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(values[0]))
    {
        var id = Convert.ToInt32(values[0]);

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(values[4]))
        {
            dic.Add(id, values[4]);
        }
    }
}
```